# replace content of multiple Files with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, replace

I'm trying to replace a certain Line in multiple logonscripts (>2000 Scripts).

The script works in the current form, but it writes every file to the disk, even when no changes are made, but I don't want this behaviour. It only should write to the disk, if changes are made.

This is what I already have:

```
$varFiles = Get-ChildItem $varPath*.$VarEnding
foreach ($file in $varFiles)
{
    (Get-Content $file) |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace [regex]::Escape("$varFind"), "$varReplace" } |
    Set-Content $file   
}
```

And this is what I already tried, but it seems, that it is not possible to use if in piped commands:

```
$varFiles = Get-ChildItem $varPath*.$VarEnding
foreach ($file in $varFiles)
{
    $control = $file
    (Get-Content $file) |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace [regex]::Escape("$varFind"), "$varReplace" } |
    If($control -ne $file){Set-Content $file}   
}
```

The variables $varPath, $varEnding, $varFind and $varReplace are defined by a few Read-Host commands at the start of the script.

I hope you guys can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity and speed - although at the expense of memory use - I'd simply cache and operate on *whole* input files (requires PowerShell v3+, due to use of `-Raw`<sup>[1]</sup>); since logon scripts are generally small, this should be acceptable:

```powershell
$varFindEscaped = [regex]::Escape($varFind)
$varReplaceEscaped = $varReplace -replace '\$', '$$$$'

foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem $varPath*$varEnding) {
  $contentBefore = Get-Content -Raw $file
  $contentAfter = $contentBefore -replace $varFindEscaped, $varReplaceEscaped
  if ($contentBefore -ne $contentAfter) {
    Set-Content $file $contentAfter
  }
}
```

- To improve performance I've moved escaping of the `-regex` operands outside the loop.

  - Note that I'm also escaping `$` instances in the *replacement* value to prevent their interpretation as references to what was matched, such as `$&` to refer to the entire match.
- Note that `Set-Content` by default uses the system's default code page rather than UTF-8 encoding.

---

<sup>[1]
In PS v2, you may omit `-Raw`, which turns `$contentBefore` into an *array* of strings (lines) on whose elements `-replace` then operates *individually* (as in the OP's approach). While probably slightly slower, it does have the advantage of performing the substitution on individual lines only rather than potentially across *multiple* lines.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I am using PS v2, so this one unfortunately doesn't work for me. Do you have a way to achieve this in PS v2?

Comment: I just removed the -raw attribute from Get-Content to use it on PS v2 and it worked like a charm on my 10 testing-files. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @LöwäCent Glad to hear it; I've added a note re `-Raw` to the answer.

Comment: RAM and CPU usage is not the issue of mine. It was more the disk-usage and DC-replication (as it would replicate 2000+ Logonscripts across about 50 DCs on 20+ sites) that worried me, so this completely works for me.

Comment: @LöwäCent: Got it, thanks. Honestly, I haven't run performance tests, so it's quite possible that there's little difference in performance between using `-Raw` and not using it in the code above.